# When did the Death Star 2 construction start?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, revenge-of-the-sith, return-of-the-jedi

I think it's safe to assume (although probably well known to everyone except me) that the DS2 construction was started long before the DS1 was blown up. As it took nearly 20 years for the DS1 to be completed, when did the construction of DS2 begin?

Comment: Ok. I seem to struggle to find questions before posting mine, any tips on how to search?

Comment: In many sites the search is crap (including here afaik), so I use google with the keyword: site:scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Answer, at the time if the Battle of Yavin.

Comment: Thanks you Rebel Scrum you

Comment: Alternatively, don't hesitate to drop by in the [chat]; users there might remember seeing a similar question. Cheers :)

Comment: Yeh bit got my head round the chat but yet but thanks. (Almost) everyone is helpful and constructive!